# Is there anyway to validate field of nested struct item from first struct in Golang?

Tags: go

```
type T1 struct{
  Test T2 `json:"test"`
} 

type T2 struct{
  Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

Scenario is that second struct(T2) comes from a library and i want to add extra
validation for the T2 struct fields in T1.
Something like(Test T2 `json:"validate:test.name:max=32"`).
so is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: No, it's not possible to modify the struct tags of an imported struct type. The only place where you can modify those tags is in the type declaration's type literal.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't change the tags on defined structs, you can instruct the validator library(assuming you are using go-playground/validator) to add extra verification to the struct type without adding tags. This is called struct level validation.

For example:

```golang
type T2 struct{
  Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

func NameLengthValidation(sl validator.StructLevel) {

    t := sl.Current().Interface().(T2)

    if len(t.Name) > 5 {
        sl.ReportError(user.Name, "name", "Name", "namelength", "")
    }
}


func main() {
    validate = validator.New()
    validate.RegisterStructValidation(UserStructLevelValidation, T2{})
    
    t := &T2{
        Name: "short"
    }

    err := validate.Struct(user)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Here is the official example: https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/master/_examples/struct-level/main.go